# Laravel page is not workingg after checkAdmin and CheckUser middleware conditions are true

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have two middlewares.one for admin uses CheckAdmin middleware.Second for staffs,teachers,emplyee uses CheckUser middleware,When i try to login the credentials it redirects the pages but it shows "page is not working".How can i resolve this issue?
checkAdmin.php(Middleware)

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    { 
        
       
            if(auth()->check() && Auth::User()->type == 1 ){
                // dd(Auth::User()->type);
                return redirect('dashboard/index');
            }else{
                return $next($request); 
            }
       
    }
```

checkUser.php(Middleware)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->check() && Auth::User() && Auth::User()->type == 3 ){
            if ((Auth::User()->status == 1) && Auth::User()->institution->status==1) {
                return redirect('employeeDashboard/index');
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 1) && Auth::User()->institution->status==0){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 0 && Auth::User()->institution->status==0)){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 0 && Auth::User()->institution->status==1)){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
        }else if(auth()->check() && Auth::User() && Auth::User()->type == 4){
            if ((Auth::User()->status == 1) && Auth::User()->institution->status==1) {
                return redirect('Staff/Home');
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 1) && Auth::User()->institution->status==0){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 0 && Auth::User()->institution->status==0)){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 0 && Auth::User()->institution->status==1)){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
        }
        else{
            return $next($request);
        }
        
    }
```

HomeController.php

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('CheckUser');
        $this->middleware('CheckAdmin');
        
    }
    public function index()
    {   
        if(auth()->check() && Auth::User() && Auth::User()->type == 5){
            if ((Auth::User()->type == 5) && (Auth::User()->status == 1)) {
                return redirect('Teacher/Home');
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 1) && Auth::User()->institution->status==0){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 0 && Auth::User()->institution->status==0)){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
            else if((Auth::User()->status == 0 && Auth::User()->institution->status==1)){
                return view('notAuthorized'); 
            }
        }
        else{
            Session::flash('error','Invalid user name or password !');
            return redirect('/');
        }
        
           
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'CheckAdmin'], function () {  
Route::get('dashboard/index', 'DashboardController@index')->name('adminDashboard');
Route::get('dashboard/videos', 'DashboardController@videos')->name('adminVideos');
Route::get('dashboard/studentRegister', 'DashboardController@studentRegister')->name('addStudents');
Route::post('/newRegister', 'DashboardController@newRegister')->name('newRegister');
Route::get('/Dashboard/getSubclasses','DashboardController@getSubclasses')->name('getSubclasses');
Route::post('/newStudent', 'DashboardController@newStudent')->name('newStudent');
Route::get('/editStudent/{id}', 'DashboardController@editStudent')->name('editStudent');
Route::post('/updateStudent', 'DashboardController@updateStudent')->name('updateStudent');
});
```

DashboardController

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('CheckAdmin');
    }
    public function index()
    {
            $students = Students::with('classes','subclasses','institution','user')->latest()->paginate(10);
            $classes = Classes::where('status', '1')->get();
            $users = User::where('type', 1)->orwhere('type',3)->get();
            return view('admin.dashboard',compact('students','classes','users'));
        
    }
```

Comment: is the code correct ?

Comment: still page is not working?